# An error occurs if unit testing is performed at the same time

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

Each unit test did not cause an error. However, it occurs when several are carried out at the same time. Is there a Google test feature that can put Sleep between unit tests running?

p.s I can not modify the source because it is not my source.

The following command causes an error.

```
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=NAV_NC_0002_RouteController_Test*:IF1_LastDestination_Test*:NAV_NC_0029_TrafficInformationController_Test*:NAV_NC_0051_RouteMonitorListController_Test*:NAV_NC_0068_LocationInformationProvider_Test*:NAV_NC_0067_LearningRecordingController_Test*
```

I want to sleep between each of these files.
If you type each in this way, no errors will occur.

```
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=NAV_NC_0002_RouteController_Test*
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=IF1_LastDestination_Test*
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=NAV_NC_0029_TrafficInformationController_Test*
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=NAV_NC_0051_RouteMonitorListController_Test*
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=NAV_NC_0068_LocationInformationProvider_Test*
./ext_libs_test --gtest_filter=NAV_NC_0067_LearningRecordingController_Test*
```

Comment: Hiding the problem won't help. Fix it instead. If you can't modify things, talk to the people that can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some dependency between test cases, and likely (but not guaranteed) a sleep will not hide this fact. What seems to hide the problem is to run the application once for each test case, so i'm guessing some static data which is not initialized per test case but per application instantiation. Try to find this problem and solve it.

Comment: In my environment, when the unit test is finished, the result is an xml file. I have to submit an integrated xml file. But the source code is not written by me, So I do not know the structure. I can't edit it. Is there no other way at all?